# Hacker News rails clone: advice on modeling relationship between links, comments and votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, data-modeling

*I'm loving Rails but we just started dating.*

A user can vote on both links and comments.  In addition to primary key and timestamp, I currently have the following attributes defined for these models:

- **Link**    url, headline, submitter_id, score
- **Comment** content, commenter_id, score, link_id, parent_comment_id
- **Vote**    id, voter_id, link_id, direction

I just added the Comment Model and thinking through how to integrate it with votes.  Some options:

1. Collapse links and comments into a single "Item" model, and map votes to the generic item_id
2. Have two vote tables, one for comments, one for links
3. Add comment_id column to existing Vote table

Not sure what's best.  #1 and #3 introduce dual-purpose tables, i.e. there are certain columns in a table that are only relevant to subsets of rows within that table.  #2 avoids this problem, but seems redundant and silly.

Is the tradeoff inevitable or am I not seeing the golden path?  What would you recommend?  And if you happen to know of a rails repository on github that handles a similar situation, I'd really appreciate a link!

Comment: Just as a side comment, dont use foreign keys as voter_id, commenter_id.... but the foreign table name (user_id) Thats the convention and if you do it this way Rails won't pick it up and you will have to specify it

Comment: The minimal effort of specifying seems worth the readability gain of submitter, voter, commenter vs. generic "user" for all three.  But perhaps I should go the "user" route and just write wrapper/alias methods for readability's sake?

Comment: You can always do in your model: `belongs_to :commenter, :class_name => 'User'` and you will be able to preserve your code readability and your schema standardization.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a polymorphic association. In your case would be as simple as :

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, :as => :votable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, :as => :votable
  #...
end
```

Your votes table should look like:

```
id           : integer
votable_id   : integer 
votable_type : string # Comment || Link
```

Here you have a Railscast about it: [Polymorphic Associations Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

Comment: This looks promising, thanks!  Looking into it now, will come back to check off the answer once I understand it.

Comment: Ok, 1 minute into the video and it's clear you hit the nail on the head.  Thank you very much!